# Footer not staying below the content

Tags: html, css

My footer doesn't seem to want to sit below my `.wrapper`.

The closest I have gotten to getting it to un-merge itself from the top the page, is by telling it to be `bottom: 0px`, but then it sits awkwardly in the middle of the page.

`clear:both` also hasn't worked.

I'm worried it may be something in the jssor JavaScript that's messing something up.

```css
#slider1_container {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  top: 50px;
  left: 40%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 900px;
  background: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #404041;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -142px;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #feede4;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="slider1_container">
      <!-- Loading Screen -->
      <div class="loading" u="loading">
        <div class="loadingStyle1"></div>
        <div class="loadingStyle2"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- Images -->
      <div u="slides" class="slides">
        <div>
          <img u="image" src="images/hotel/full/image-29.jpg" />
          <img u="thumb" src="images/hotel/thumbnail/image-29.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img u="image" src="images/hotel/full/image-30.jpg" />
          <img u="thumb" src="images/hotel/thumbnail/image-30.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img u="image" src="images/hotel/full/image-31.jpg" />
          <img u="thumb" src="images/hotel/thumbnail/image-31.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img u="image" src="images/hotel/full/image-32.jpg" />
          <img u="thumb" src="images/hotel/thumbnail/image-32.jpg" />
        </div>
        <!-- Arrow Left --> <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top: 158px; left: 248px;">
                </span>

        <!-- Arrow Right --> <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top: 158px; right: 8px">
                </span>

        <!-- thumbnail navigator container -->
        <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort02" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
          <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
          <div u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
            <div u="prototype" class="p">
              <div class=w>
                <div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
              </div>
              <div class=c></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>jasoldk;as'dlas'd</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cowc1uv1/

Comment: I believe it's because your using absolute positioning, which is offsetting the footer, create a JSFiddle using a brief parts of your code which re-creates your problem, this way we can directly interact and try and fix your code - http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sorry, apologies guys. I did figure out the answer, @nabrown78 caught that it was a positioning conflict. I needed to remove the positioning and add a clearfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two styles causing trouble on `#slide1_container`:

```
#slider1_container{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    top: 50px;
    left: 40%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 900px;
    background: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

There is no point in floating and absolutely positioning something. But either one will cause issues with the next elements in your layout. If you absolutely position something, you remove it entirely from the layout flow. So, to subsequent elements it effectively has no height (so your footer appears at the top). If you float the element, you have to "clear the float". One way to do this is to use a [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) on a container element. You also need to remove `position:absolute` from your footer.

Your logos and colors are looking good...if you learn some basic CSS layout techniques, especially [how the various values for position really work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), you will save yourself frustration and time in building your site.

Comment: Ah! The clearfix is truly a god amongst CSS hacks. It worked perfectly. Somehow it even fixed the container for the JS box too. (I moved the footer outside of the `.slider1_container` so now I removed the positioning from `.wrapper` and `.slider1_container` and finally it works.

Also, thank you so much for the comment on the design. The CSS layout techniques are by far the biggest problem I have, so I'm going to have to go back to the start and see if I missed anything.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

With `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`, as you mention in your question, your `footer` element does indeed descend to the bottom of *its absolutely positioned container* (`div class="wrapper"`), as it's supposed to.

The problem you're having with the remaining gap below the footer involves your `div id="slider1_container`. See the `height: 1046.51955032362px` and `position: absolute` properties. Try turning those off in Chrome Developer Tools (or the code inspector of whatever browser you're using) and your `<footer>` block descends to the actual bottom of the screen.

Keep in mind that an element with `position: absolute` is positioned in relation to its nearest positioned ancestor, or the initial container if there isn't one. It does not necessarily position the element at the bottom of the viewport.

Depending on how you plan to use your JS slider, you may need to play with the height and absolute positioning values (`top` & `left`) to meet your needs.

Comment: The last paragraph really helped with the fallout from the effects of @nabrown78's response. Thank you! - I've had to reconfigure the heights and weights, as percentages seem to be causing problems.